# Как отправить куки в middleware Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, cookie

Как отправить куки непосредственно в мидлвере? 
Вариант

```
return $next($request)->cookie('switch', $sw);
```

не работает.
При дебаге собственное куки присутствует в заголовках, но когда я пытаюсь получить куки в каком нибудь контроллере

```
$request->cookie('switch')
```

то получаю `null`
Версия лары 5.8, php 7.1

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#accessing-the-request

> Alternatively, you can use the Cookie facade to "queue" cookies for attachment to the outgoing response from your application. The queue method accepts a Cookie instance or the arguments needed to create a Cookie instance. These cookies will be attached to the outgoing response before it is sent to the browser:

Перевод

> В качестве альтернативы, вы можете использовать Фасад Cookie, чтобы «ставить в очередь» куки для прикрепления к исходящему ответу из вашего приложения. Метод queue принимает экземпляр Cookie или аргументы, необходимые для создания экземпляра Cookie. Эти файлы cookie будут прикреплены к исходящему ответу до его отправки в браузер:

```
Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('name', 'value', $minutes));

Cookie::queue('name', 'value', $minutes);
```

Comment: Это не сработало, когда я добавил ob_start() в начало метода handle() мидлвер класса, вот только тогда отправились куки. Но я думаю должно как-то работать и без старта буферизации... Такое впечатление, что заголовки уже были отправлены

Comment: Кстати в контроллере `return $next($request)->cookie('switch', $sw);`  эта конструкция работает без проблем.